# How to add excel spreadsheet data to a bar in a Power Point slide

Tags: powerpoint, embed, spreadsheet

I have been tasked with creating a Power Point slide that shows individual bars on the slide. Each bar will reflect the data for that bar which comes from an Excel Spreadsheet. See example.
HOw do I embed the correct data into each bar? And can the data be pulled in automatically from the spreadsheet?

I create the bar object, but I don't see any way to embed the data into the bar and also into the "key" on the right hand side of the chart.